# How to install appium in windows, once its downloaded npm?

Tags: appium

I have downloaded requirements (appium, npm, sdk, gi) for appium installation but how to install them to make it run on andriod device.

it would great help if you provid the step by step procedure to install.

thankyou.

RAM

Answer (score 3):

Download Necessary Files

1. Eclipse Standard: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr (ie eclipse-standard-kepler-R-win32-x86_64.zip)
2. Appium for Windows: http://appium.io/ (ie
   AppiumForWindows-0.10.1.zip)
3. Selenium WebDriver 2.0 (Java Client): 
   http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.35.0.zip
4. JDK:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
   (ie jdk-7u40-windows-x64.exe)
5. Android SDK Tools (ADT Bundle for Windows:
   http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (ie
   installer_r22.2.1-windows.exe)

Installation

1. Unzip the Downloaded Files
2. Create a new folder, C:\AppAutomation and Extract the downloaded
   files to, C:\AppAutomation
3. Install the Java Development Kit
4. NAVIGATE to where the JDK executable has been downloaded
5. Install the JDK by DOUBLE-CLICKING the executable and following
   through installation wizard
6. Install the Android Development Tools Bundle for Windows
7. NAVIGATE to where the ADT executable has been downloaded and Install
   the ADT by DOUBLE-CLICKING the executable and following through
   installation wizard
8. When Eclipse restarts, it may complain about missing tools. CLICK OK
9. AVD Manager will load, CHECK Tools in the Name column and follow
   through with install 
   Configure Eclipse and Sample Project
10. Navigate to the folder where you extracted Eclipse to DOUBLE-CLICK
     “C:\AppAutomation\eclipse\eclipse.exe” CLICK “OK” to work space
     popup
    Install TestNG
11. CLICK “Install New Software…” under “HELP” in the Main Menu
12. INPUT “http://beust.com/eclipse” in the Work with input box
13. CLICK Add… CHECK TestNG in the Name column CLICK Next, Agree to all
     the terms, CLICK Finish when wizard completes installation.

Install Android ADT

1. CLICK “Install New Software…” under “HELP” in the Main Menu
2. INPUT “https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/” in the Work with
   input box CLICK Add… CHECK Developer Tools in the Name column
3. CLICK Next, Agree to all the terms, CLICK Finish when wizard
   completes installation.  Create Sample Project
4. CLICK File > New > Java Project from the main menu
5. INPUT “Sample Project” for a project name CLICK Finish

Add Selenium JAR References

1. In the Package Explorer, RIGHT-CLICK on the newly created project,
   “Sample Project”
2. CLICK Configure Build Path… under Build Path in the context menu
   CLICK Add External JARS…
3. In the JAR Selection dialog, NAVIGATE to the directory where
   Selenium has been extracted to (ie C:\AppAutomation\selenium-2.35.0)
   SELECT all JARs in the selenium home folder
4. CLICK Open
5. CLICK Add External JARS… to add remaining JARs
6. In the JAR Selection dialog, NAVIGATE to the Selenium\libs directory
   (ie C:\AppAutomation\selenium-2.35.0\libs)
7. SELECT all JARs in the selenium libs folder
8. CLICK Open CLICK OK

I think that’s it…

Next Step… Create a sample script…

Comment: it does not say anywhere how to start appium. Actually I am stuck at the place where clicking on appium.exe says it is not a valid win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Android SDK, set ANDROID_HOME environment variable with value as SDK installation directory
2. Install JAVA Development kit(JDK), set JAVA_HOME environment variable with value as JDK installation directory
3. Add below to existing value of environment variable PATH:
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platforms;
4. Open Eclipse, add ADT plugin from Eclipse market place, start Android device manager and launch android device by creating from templates available
5. Download node.js msi installer from https://nodejs.org/en/ and install it
6. Download AppiumForWindows from http://appium.io/ -> Downloads, unzip it and install it.
7. Launch Appium at end of installation and click play button after it is done with searching updates.
8. Open command prompt and type command adb devices, it should list emulator device you have launched and any android device if connected with usb debugging on in developer options from settings.
9. Create scripts in preferred language by adding it's Selenium bindings/jar in a new project.
10. Happy learning Appium automation!!